# Make object move to player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been looking on the internet for the answer to my problem. I couldn't find anything that worked so I decided to post it here.

I keep getting the error: `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"`

When doubleclicking it sends me to this:

```
`transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, player.transform.position, 3f);  //move towards character`
```

I created random meshes (asteroids, this works) and they are supposed to move towards the Player (error!).

To make the Asteroids chase my Player, I added the following variables on top:

```
 bool hitPlayer = false;
 GameObject player;
```

I added this in the start function:

```
player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
```

and I added this in the update function:

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, player.transform.position, 3f);  //move towards character
```

Here is my complete code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RandomAsteroid : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Material material;
    private Material collectedMaterial;
    private MeshRenderer meshRenderer;
    private Collider collider;


    bool hitPlayer = false;
    GameObject player;


    // Use this for initialization

    void Start()
    {
        collectedMaterial = (Material) Resources.Load("sun", typeof(Material));

        Vector3 v0 = new Vector3(Random.Range(1f,5f), 1, Random.Range(1f,5f));
        Vector3 v1 = new Vector3(Random.Range(1f,5f), 1, Random.Range(-1f,-5f));
        Vector3 v2 = new Vector3(Random.Range(-1f,-5f), 1, Random.Range(-1f,-5f));
        Vector3 v3 = new Vector3(Random.Range(-1f,-5f), 1, Random.Range(1f,5f));

        Vector3 v4 = new Vector3(Random.Range(1f,5f), -1, Random.Range(1f,5f));
        Vector3 v5 = new Vector3(Random.Range(1f,5f), -1, Random.Range(-1f,-5f));
        Vector3 v6 = new Vector3(Random.Range(-1f, -5f), -1, Random.Range(-1f, -5f));
        Vector3 v7 = new Vector3(Random.Range(-1f,-5f), -1, Random.Range(1f,5f));

        MeshFilter meshFilter = gameObject.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
        meshRenderer = gameObject.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();


        meshRenderer.material = material;

        Mesh mesh = meshFilter.mesh;

        mesh.Clear();

        Vector3[] duplicateVertices = new Vector3[]
            {
                //top 
                v0, //0
                v1, //1
                v2, //2
                v3, //3

                //front
                v4, //4
                v0, //5
                v3, //6
                v7, //7

                //left
                v5, //8
                v1, //9
                v0, //10
                v4, //11

                //back
                v6, //12
                v2, //13
                v1, //14
                v5, //15

                //right
                v7, //16
                v3, //17
                v2, //18
                v6, //19

                //bottom
                v5, //20
                v4, //21
                v7, //22
                v6 //23
            };

        mesh.vertices = duplicateVertices;


        int[] triangles = new int[]
            {
                //top
                0, 1, 2,
                2, 3, 0,

                //front
                4, 5, 6,
                6, 7, 4,

                //left
                8, 9, 10,
                10, 11, 8,

                //back
                12, 13, 14,
                14, 15, 12,

                //right
                16, 17, 18,


 18, 19, 16,

            //bottom
            20, 21, 22,
            22, 23, 20


        };
    mesh.triangles = triangles;
    Collider collider = gameObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider> ();

    mesh.RecalculateNormals();
    mesh.RecalculateBounds ();
    mesh.Optimize();

    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (!hitPlayer)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, player.transform.position, 3f);  //move towards character
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision){

    if (collision.gameObject.name == "Player")
    {
        meshRenderer.material = collectedMaterial;
    }

}
```

}

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: It may be as simple as `gameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");` instead of `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");` ... use the debugger to find out.

Comment: @Filburt that doesn't work at all :(

Comment: That was a mere guess at why maybe your `player` is `null`. It's also not clear from the code shown, where `transform` is declared and initialized. Put a breakpoint on the line your getting to error and inspect your objects.

Comment: Well, obviously `player` is `null`. It is `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag()`. If you don't find anything, have a look if you have any object with that tag.

Comment: I have an empty GameObject named Player, in that empty GameObject I have a spaceship

Comment: @MeindertStijfhals Well, that is not what it should be. Have a look at the answer down below: The name of the object doesn't matter for this, the tag does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is likely from `player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");`
If you you don't have a GameOBject that is tagged as "Player" then that is the problem. Tag is different from naming. If your gameObject is named "Player" then use `GameObject.Find()` instead of `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag()`.

So replace

```
player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player")
```

with

```
player = GameObject.Find("Player");
```